Pivotal's definition on arrow's impossible theorem
I'm trying to understand Arrow's impossible theorem, and I understand the idea of using extremal lemma. The pivotal is defined as the first individual who change his preference of from ranking $b$ to bottom to ranking $b$ to top.
But I see another definition. It defines $i$ is pivotal over $(a,b)$ as there exists a preference profile that $a\succ_i b$ and $b\succ_j a$ for all $j\neq i$, and the SWF gives social preference as $a\succ b$. I have no idea how to prove the existence of such a pivotal.
I'm thinking of using Condorcet cycle to prove it by contradiction, but we don't have majority rule here.

Which source are you using? Typically assumed, that we are in non-degenerate choice system where we have majority rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem.
